# Where to store static methods in OOP?

Tags: php, oop, static

I have a Blog class that does exactly what you think it would...create an object and handle it. That part is nice and clean.

I am now in need of a function that will quickly return a number of all the blogs in my database (not necessarily related to the blog object). Therefore, I am thinking a static method would be a good choice.

My question is, where should I store this static method? Here are a few options I can think of:

- store it as a static method in the Blog class (maybe smelly because it has nothing to do with the object that class creates?)
- create a new class for blog static functions (seems excessive)
- find a better way to go about this altogether (yes, but what?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably something is managing the multiple Blog objects you create? If not, there should be, and that's where the method belongs - no need for it to be static.

Comment: indeed...my controller (MVC) manages it...but i will be reusing the need for this function on several pages...from what i've read, its better to localize this funcationality, right?

Comment: A controller in an MVC solution (and I personally think MVC is pants) should have no business level knowledge - it should use a business level object to get the work done, and that business level object is where your function should reside.

Comment: aka, the model? sorry...if its not clear...i am definitely stepping into a new world for me

Comment: and, if thats the case...i guess if i am creating a business level object, that is kind of what im asking. do i put it in the Blog object, or create a new one?

Comment: Once again,the model in an MVC solution should refer to business level objects. This means you can use the business level objects in in non-MVC designs. I haye to suggest the dreaded "manager" type of object, but what you seem to need is a "BlogManager" class.

Comment: okay i think i get it...i appreciate the patience, neil...that seems to be the most inline with what im already doing and the most reusable.

Answer (score 2):

Create a class/interface called `BlogService` which will have `count` method in it. Other methods such as `findAll`, `findById`, etc.

Comment: so this would keep it from being static?

Comment: Yes. static members make code less object oriented and hard to unit test. For instance, static methods can't be overriden.

Comment: I like this solution, but not due to the nature of statics.  The way I generally code is such that I have a 'Service' class that manages multiple models of the same kind, and takes care of operations on groups of models, so that my model classes represent a single business object or entity.  I find that doing it this way, allows me to easily abstract away all of the 'manangement' of the objects as a group, and leave the model dealing with only a single business object.

Answer (score 1):

You could also encapsulate the database access in a class and add the new method there.

Answer (score 1):

> find a better way to go about this
>   altogether (yes, but what?)

**Model View Controller**

Transform  your Blog to a 'Controller' at this stage

Create a 'Model' that can handle all your database methods

From Class Blog call the Model as you wish (also suggest at this point refactor all database requests to go into Model).

(For a very good Introduction to MVC search for  CodeIgniter).

Answer (score 0):

You do not need static method, but static variable. Static method is just function in object that does not take object but only variables from outside.